# Discriminated against by solicitations of donations for Ukraine at checkout

Tags: england-and-wales, discrimination

Meet Bob. Bob deeply opposes the world order of NATO imperialism and finds the Ukrainian NATO backed regime repulsive and abhorrent due to its perceived Nazi associations in his mind. (Bob vehemently abhors Nazism.)

Bob further feels disgusted by all of the propaganda with which he feels he is incessantly bombarded from all directions by society. He feels very exhausted as this incessant propaganda siege grates and wears on him and besides he feels that it is a form of morally repulsive virtue signalling by people who don't actually harbor the proclaimed virtue at all.

It is to Bob arguably as though the state has officially endorsed a worldview that is dedicated to actively condemning his own so as to make him feel alone, inferior, and utterly marginalized.

One day, Bob goes out to buy some stuff and after inserting his card to the payment terminal, he is asked if he would like to add a donation to the Ukrainian cause to his payment.

No such offer is made for him to donate to the Russian federation's war widows/orphans, or to the Russian federation's armed forces, or to the antifascist people's republics of Donetsk and Lugansk. He now feels further marginalised and vilified by society.

Now meet Alice. Alice sports Ukrainian flag badges and bumper stickers and can't stop telling everyone how much she hates Vladimir Putin. Alice visits the same shop and is offered the same option when paying for her purchase. Alice leaves with a warm, pleased smile on her face as her worldview has been affirmed.

Has Bob been treated less favourably than Alice by this establishment with respect to his committed philosophical worldview of opposing fascism and all its associations and forms? Has Bob thus been unlawfully discriminated against?

Comment: Bob was treated exactly the same way as Alice - so how can he have been treated less favorably?

Comment: That is irrelevant. If his believe is genuinely and deeply held on the basis of committed anti fascist beliefs it should be protected.

Comment: Anti fascism should be worthy of respect in a democratic society.

Comment: Nobody denied Bob his beliefs, or denied him anything based on those beliefs, they just didn't cater to them.

Comment: True anti-fascism is respected in the wider world.  Actions based on fake anti-fascism beliefs are rightly derided.

Comment: Okay wherever. Show the basis of this in law and we can talk.

Comment: Bobs feelings are hurt due to having a minority political view point. It is different from the store’s view. The store and Bob are both entitled to their views. Bob can donate to Russian orphans, just not as conveniently as others can donate to Ukraine orphans. Nothing in your scenario shows bob’s beliefs being prohibited or limited.

Comment: Minority viewpoints can still be protected cheaper. And the inconvenience you had just described is discriminatory unfavorable treatment. This is substantive injury. The resulting hurt feelings which you mention would be the added insult which may be factored into quantum of damages under the venti scale.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite the law doesn’t protect you from hurt feelings

Comment: Not sure what protected cheaper was meant to say, but maybe it was protected beliefs.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite we are dealing in discrimination here not in restriction of expression.

Comment: @DaleM sometimes it does. Ever heard of intentional/negligent induction of emotional distress? Or public order offences, or public outrage, or anti social behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Has Bob been treated less favourably than Alice by this establishment with respect to his committed philosophical worldview of opposing fascism and all its associations and forms? Has Bob thus been unlawfully discriminated against?

No.

There is no discrimination law engaged here by the retailer asking if its customer would like to [donate to the Red Cross Crisis in Ukraine Appeal](https://donate.redcross.org.uk/appeal/ukraine-crisis-appeal) or such and not asking if the customer would like to donate to any other appeal.

Answer (score 2):

### No

The store owner is entitled to freedom of political expression. If that motivates them to politely ask all customers to donate to a particular cause, that's neither discrimination nor unlawful discrimination.

Bob is entitled to freedom of political expression. Other people are entitled to exercise their freedom of political expression by calling Bob out for his views. If Bob is hurt by this, he has the right to keep his opinions to himself and avoid the disapprobation they provoke.

This is based on an even more fundamental right: Bob has the right to reap the consequences of his actions.

Comment: Who called Bob out for his views and what relevance does that have to the question?